# How to detect Key Release Event in Qt using QxtGlobalShortcut library

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5.5

I use QxtGlobalShortcut library. When I want to detect SIGNAL(activated()) it works perfectly, but it fires when I press the key. How to detect that I released the key when my app is minimized?

Answer (score 1):

Qxt is shipped as plain code. Change [this](https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt/src/696423b68972fc9edae318558b8ce26dc187cc40/src/widgets/x11/qxtglobalshortcut_x11.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#qxtglobalshortcut_x11.cpp-172) line. Thats just for x11. Dont forget win and macos.